# Yii2 pjax file upload for use within activeForm

Tags: yii2, pjax, active-form

I'm creating a Yii2 activeForm for creating and editing a product, and want the page to manage images as well. I want to be able to upload (add) images for the product, and then have a sortable preview region where the images show up and can be sorted to the right order. My plan is to upload files via ajax/pjax to a temporary folder where the form will pull from to display them in the sortable region, and upon saving the model, the images will be moved/named accordingly.

Initially I'm using [Kartik's FileInput widget](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput) (which may be unnecessary) and [Kartik's Sortable Input](http://demos.krajee.com/sortable-input) for re-ordering the images.

I believe I can handle the file uploading and moving/renaming, my question is how do I upload the images separate from the rest of the form, and then have the ActiveForm pull them into the sortable input area? Additionally, I'll want to be able to delete images from it as well (with a little x in the corner of the thumbnail). I'm familiar with using pjax to wrap grid-views and even using pjax to submit a form to a pjax method (for use inside a modal), but not sure how to use it inside another form and make the other form dynamically load the images.

To clarify, I have a `Product` that extends `ActiveRecord`, and a `ImageForm` that extends `Model`. I then have `ProductController` with the following `Create` action:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Product();
    $images = new ImageForm();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'images' => $images,
    ]);
}
```

My goal is to be able to upload images (through `ImageForm`) to a temporary location that is displayed on the Product's `create` view. However currently, using the upload function in the widget merely reloads the page and the images are gone.

Comment: well you can use  `formModel` that extends `yii\base\Model` to upload the file using the `kartik\FileInput` I don't see any problem in doing that your normal form will have a separate model which is extended from `\yii\db\ActiveRecord`, you can use the events provided by `FileInput` widget to refresh the `div` in which you want to show the uploaded files or make a separate `action` in your `controller` that is called by this `event` using `ajax`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam is there a 'yii' way of doing that ajax call, or am I just writing javascript to detect the event? Also, how do I submit just the upload form and not the entire product form?

Comment: if you use the `kartik\FileInput` you dont have to write the javascript to post the picture it has the option to trigger upload as soon you select the file and as it uses `ActiveForm` and `model` so yes it is a `yii` way of doing the upload it will even show you the validation too from model if it fails. like if size limit increases

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam pardon my ignorance, I'm using the fileInput in a `$form->field()->widget` scenario, would I have to embed another activeForm inside the first to make this work? And once the upload is complete how do I trigger the refresh? Is that custom javascript or is there a way to trigger it otherwise? I'm going to work on it a bit and will update my question as appropriate.

Comment: the `FileInput` you are using should use the same `ActiveForm` but a different model object that would be of your `UploadForm` class i.e `$form->field('imagefileName',$uploadModel)->widget()`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam That's where you've lost me. I have `$model` representing the product (ActiveRecord) and `$images` representing the image form (Model), and when I hit the upload button on the widget, the form submits (or fails with validation errors on the other fields) and the page refreshes with my input data, upload field clear, and the images haven't been uploaded anywhere.

Comment: you should use ajax upload option and provide `uploadUrl` for fileInput so that it won't submit your form

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I didn't know about uploadUrl to make it ajax, thanks for that. I set it and it's going to my method correctly, however the post data only contains a value `file_id`, and I still don't see how this would trigger the parent form to refresh and grab the images once they're processed.

Comment: see the answer i added hope that helps you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a separate model for Uploading the image and use the same form with just passing the `$uploadForm` model object to populate the form field for the `file`, you can use the `kartik\FileInput` widget which has the option to upload file via `ajax` via `uploadUrl`, you can trigger the upload on the selection of the file automatically via `fileUploaded` event and once uploaded you have 2 options either you use [**`uploadAsync=>true`**](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-options#uploadAsync) and use [**`filebatchuploadsuccess`**](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-events#filebatchuploadsuccess) which triggers after all files are uploaded or use default setting and use [**`filebatchuploadcomplete`**](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-events#filebatchuploadcomplete) wchich will trigger after every file upload. Both of these events provide the list of files that are uploaded but be careful as you are validating the files after they are submitted you should return the response in case of error so that the user is notified for the files that were not uploaded, you can either the files list provided by the events or better use a separate `action` inside your controller and call it inside the relative success function you are using via an `ajax` call and populate the list of the uploaded files if you are saving them inside a table query the table to show the names

[**`fileselect`**](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-events#fileselect) :
This event is triggered after files are selected in the file input via the file browse button. This is slightly different than the change event in the sense that this will be triggered even if the file browse dialog is canceled.

**How you are going to use it**

```
//get filinput object
var $input=$("#input-id");

 $input.on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {

    //trigger file upload with 1 sec delay
    setTimeout(function() {
    $input.fileinput("upload");
}, 1000);
});
```

[**`filebatchuploadcomplete`**](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-events#filebatchuploadcomplete): This event is triggered only for ajax uploads and after completion of either the synchronous OR asynchronous ajax batch upload.

> Additional parameters available are:
>
> - files: the file stack array (or empty object if not available).
> - extra: the uploadExtraData settings for the plugin (or empty object if not available).

Sample Code

```
$('#input-id').on('filebatchuploadcomplete', function(event, files, extra) {
    //call the ajax function here to query the files that are uploaded
});
```

Comment: I didn't go with this exact answer, but it did lead me to the a solution. I used the first bit of JS to auto submit the form (not necessary with the upload button provided by the plugin, but I like this touch), I then wrapped the `activeForm` in pjax and then in the `filebatchuploadcomplete` event, I reloaded the pjax, so I can use the controller for more direct control.

Comment: yeah, you can do it that way too if that suite you. it will work, glad you were able to solve it  @sharf